# WPF GUI not updating on load when waiting for event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, .net-4.6

In my application I have a `view` that's being opened in the following way:

```
ManagerView view = new ManagerView();
view.ShowDialog();
```

This is the `View`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfUpdateGui.ManagerView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfUpdateGui">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ManagerViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ContentRendered">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Messages}" />
```

and my `ViewModel`:

```
public class ManagerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /*INPC Members...*/

    private string _messages;
    private static EventWaitHandle _timerWaiter;

    /*Constructor*/

    public ManagerViewModel()
    {
        _timerWaiter = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(StartProcess);
    }

    private void StartProcess()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                AddMessage("Starting");

                Worker worker = new Worker();
                worker.DidSomethingEvent += Worker_DidSomethingEvent;
                worker.DoSomeThing();

                _timerWaiter.WaitOne();

                AddMessage("Finished");
            }));
    }

    private void AddMessage(string message)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Messages += $"\r\n{message}");
    }

    private void Worker_DidSomethingEvent()
    {
        _timerWaiter.Set();
    }

    public RelayCommand LoadedCommand { get; set; }

    public string Messages
    {
        get { return _messages; }
        set
        {
            if (value == Messages) return;

            _messages = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Messages");
        }
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public event Action DidSomethingEvent;

    public void DoSomeThing()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2500);
        DidSomethingEvent();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the first message I want to display ("Starting") is displayed only after the `EventWaitHandle` was set, even tough it was added before the `WaitOne()` call.

Comment: I suppose it's because of Priority - ApplicationIdle... So when it begin? When you saw your message.

Comment: Also, did you test it on release build without debugger?

Comment: I have tested it on my end and its working fine. But without the xaml reference to DataContext. Is the ManagerViewModel  singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace ContentRendered with Loaded event and it should work. ( It did work with me).